# SQL Time Zone / DST issue

Tags: t-sql

I have a TIME column in SQL, stored in Eastern Standard Time. I'm trying to convert that time to UTC. I'm running into issues with sometimes DST is calculated, sometimes it is not.

Take the following code for example:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (T TIME);
INSERT INTO @Temp (T) VALUES ('15:00');
SELECT T, 
GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time', 
CAST(T AS DATETIME) AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time' 
FROM @Temp
```

The results of this query are:

```
15:00:00.0000000    
2019-04-19 18:08:14.090 -04:00    
1900-01-01 15:00:00.000 -05:00
```

So the question is, if both times are 'Eastern Standard Time', why does one date have an offset of -04:00 (Correct) and the other have an offset of -05:00 (Only correct when we are not on DST)

Comment: Maybe it is because of the month and day?  Daylight savings time is diferent in Aprial as it is in January 1st.  For your 2 dates.

Comment: Brad, you're right. I completely missed that.

Comment: Glad to help, it stood out because of the 1900 year which got my attention

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the TIME datatype, when cast to a datetime, has a date of 1/1/1900, which is legitimately in the -05:00 offset. To solve this problem, I added the current date to the TIME, and now everything works as expected.

```
CAST(T AS DateTime) + CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DateTime) AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time'
```